# Why BeautifulSoup gives me more tags than available?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm extracting the audios of a bunch of words from [Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/) using `BeautifulSoup` in Python. Here's the code:

```py
#!/bin/python3

import sys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:106.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/106.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
}

response = requests.get(sys.argv[1], headers=headers)

print("HTTP Response Status Code:", response.status_code)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

print(list(soup.find(class_="phonetics")))
```

when I run the program using the following command

```bash
./english_audio.py "https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hello_1?q=hello"
```

Comment: Would be great if you could add some more details, so everybody would be able to understand. 

What is meant by "more tags than available"? What is your expeted result? ... Thanks for improving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why when I convert it to list its length becomes 4?

It is returned what you have selected a [`bs4.element.Tag`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#kinds-of-objects) - An object corresponding to the single `<span>` with class `phonetics` that is parent of other tag elements nested in it.

This `bs4.element.Tag` is iterable:

```
for e in soup.find(class_="phonetics"):
    print(e.name)
```

and lead to:

```
None
div
None
div
```

Exactly this is what the built-in `list()` function is doing, it converts an iterable object, such as a string or tuple, to a `list`.

---

You have to select more specific to get only the first audio link in your `<span>` - I used [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) here to simplify chaining of selectors:

```
soup.select_one('.phonetics [data-src-mp3]').get('data-src-mp3')
```

or to get a `list` of all for hello:

```
[e.get('data-src-mp3') for e in soup.select('.phonetics [data-src-mp3]')]
```

Comment: If it's a single tag, why when I convert it to list its length becomes 4?

Comment: @AmirrezaA. Because iterating over a tag (i.e. using `list()`) returns the _children_ of that tag, and that tag has four child tags.

Comment: @HedgeHog I appreciate your edit. But I still don't get why are some of children have the name `None`. Which html tag is being mapped to `None`?

Comment: @JohnGordon Thanks for the comment. I'm still a little fuzzy on why 2 of the 4 children are empty and have the name `None` as I described in the other comment. An explanation of that would be appreciated.

Comment: @AmirrezaA. Because these are from type `<class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>`  https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#bs4.NavigableString the `print(e.name)` was just for demonstration you also could use `print(type(e))` instead, it depends on what you want to know about the elements in the `bs4.element.Tag ` you iterate.